# I need to check a column for specific text and if found run a formula elsewhere

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

In column B I have a name, (John, Jane, etc,) in column C I have text (orange, blue, etc.) I would like to check column B for a certain name and finding that name I need to run a COUNTIF formula for the possible texts in column C. My problem is I only want to count the cells pertaining to one name. So I could say John got 6 orange's, 5 blue's etc.

Comment: What are you counting? Would a countif or countifs work? Or do you need VBA? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to count the number of times the text appears in column C. The problem with running a generic countif is I would have to select the rows pertaining to the name in B. I have to do this on multiple sheets and it would be best if I could just copy and paste the formula. I need to count the number of times a word appears in column C but only if specific words are in B. For example how many times does John get orange, blue etc. How many does Jane etc.

Comment: Sounds like you want a countifs, but you'll need to have relative arguments

Comment: Does it have to be a formula? Have you considered using a simple pivot table? That is what they are designed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Probably I'm looking at the problem from another perspective, so rather  than giving you the formula, I'm trying to show you how you can use pivot table to achieve what you want.  See the image below.
[image]

See if this helps.
If you would want to know how to make Pivot tables - you can **google** it easily.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I had in mind, but it will do the job. I rarely use pivot tables so I didn't even consider this. Thank you very much.